# Calling variadic printf() from variadic C++ function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

There are 2 ways of doing it:

```cpp
template<class arg, class... args>
void test1(arg format, args... va)
{
    printf(format, va...);
}

void test2(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

test1("x = %i, pi = %.2f.\r\n", 42, 3.1415926535);
test2("x = %i, pi = %.2f.\r\n", 42, 3.1415926535);
```

Both function do the same, what are the pros and cons of each approach?

When I google for "variadic functions in C++" I get the C style `stdarg` answer first.
Then "see variadic templates...".

I've read about both, and for the first glance the templated function seems neater. Shorter code, much more readable. But are there any catches? Which one is faster?

Comment: The former(that uses variadic template) is *type-safe*.

Comment: Variadic template gains you type safety. VA args are not type safe and should not be used in C++.

Comment: @JesperJuhl anything that functionally replaces them will not be type-safe either without huge cost in code used.  That is , they are run-time, while  template is compile-time.

Comment: @n.m yea, if run-time cost isn't an issue. Sadly, it more non-deterministic than C-style format, I think that one wouldn't go away for awhile. {fmt} is much better for "front-end" and serialization. C-format gets reproduction in various frameworks where those calls happen often. On other hand, `{fmt}` is more flexible.

Comment: Don't use either one. Use [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) (or [`{fmt}`](https://fmt.dev) prior to C++20) instead, eg: `cout << format("x = {}, pi = {}.\n", 42, 3.1415926535);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. `std::format` seems to be more C++ way of doing this, however, would you still prefer it on embedded?